# Is GCD's dispatch_get_main_queue allowed when inside a block?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, restkit-0.20, mbprogresshud

Fellow Programmers,

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with the following bit of code as it doesn't work when trying to get main queue to init an UIImageView? Is this allowed within a block? Do I need to worry about getting the main queue or should I just init the UIImageView directly within the block? If I set the HUD.customView to nil it works. I am using RestKit to POST a request and showing an MDProgressHUD while it's doing the call.

```
[objectManager.HTTPClient postPath:@"/items/create"
                        parameters:parameters
                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
                               NSLog(@"Success!");

                               __block UIImageView *imageView;
                               dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"];
                                   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                               });

                               self.HUD.customView = imageView;
                               self.HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                               self.HUD.labelText = @"Success";

                               [self.HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
                           }
                           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                               [self.HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2.0];
                           }];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` is not thread-safe. Anything and everything related to `UIKit` needs to be done on the main thread. Performing operations on `UIKit` elements on other threads will have unpredictable outcomes, which is precisely the case here.

You need to use the HUD related code in the main thread. HUD is also an `UIKit` element.

```
__weak YourClass *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    //Modify the HUD
    weakSelf.HUD.customView = imageView;
    weakSelf.HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    weakSelf.HUD.labelText = @"Success";
    [weakSelf.HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
});
```

One precaution, when using `self` in blocks you need to create and use a `weak` reference to avoid retain cycle.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Amar, can I just ask why you set weakSelf = nil in your block? Does this free up memory? Also when I try to do the same I get a compiler error saying 'Variable not assignable (missing __block type specifier)'.

Comment: @amergin That assignment may not be necessary.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Amar - I'm still trying to get my head around blocks and ARC

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `init` UI-objects in main thread. But all operations with UI must be performed in main thread.
So if you want to create some subview or your want to fetch some data, you can make it in background. But when you want to add it on your controller's view or you want to reload view, you have to do it in main thread.

And Yes, `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is allowed inside blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` and `failure` blocks are already called on the main thread (you can add a log to check this is the case), this is done for you by RestKit. So, when you call `dispatch_sync` you could be blocking the main thread waiting for itself. So, generally you should be using `dispatch_async`, but in this case you should just remove this attempted thread switch.